# How do I make go-plus with Atom.io aware that I'm developing on a server?

Tags: go, sftp, atom-editor

I'm using `Atom.io` as my primary editor for Go development with the [go-plus plugin](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus).
It works great locally and the linter finds any issues in the code.

But if I use something like Transmit to SFTP into my server and edit a file with Atom, if I try to `import` a package I have on my server, it will think it's not present (because it's looking locally?) and the linter will put up an error.

How do I make it aware that I'm on a server and to look on the server for packages and such, not locally?

Answer (score 1):

If you use go install outside `GOPATH` you will see:

```
go install: no install location for directory outside GOPATH
```

so the workaround I found for this is to
set `GOPATH` to network location.
and clone other packages under your `GOPATH` folder and set imports normally.

Mounting SMB share by using mount command:

```
mount –t smbfs 192.168.0.1:/share1 /mnt –o username=UserName,workgroup=test
```

See this for how to mount it to a local drive:    [How do I use a Samba server location for GOPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679294/how-do-i-use-a-samba-server-location-for-gopath/38680558#38680558)

ref:
http://www.linuxnix.com/8-ways-to-mount-smbfs-samba-file-system-in-linux/

Comment: Interesting! Could you elaborate on how I would do this?