# How do I use a Samba server location for GOPATH?

Tags: linux, go

I am trying to set my GOPATH to a shared network folder. When I enter

```
export GOPATH=smb://path/to/shared/folder
```

I get:

```
go: GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "smb".
Run 'go help gopath' for usage.
```

I've also tried to prefix the path w/ "/" but then it tries to make a folder in root.

thx!

Comment: This is not supported. You will have to mount the file system and set the `GOPATH` to that mounted path. (Additionally, your file browser may have already mounted the share just be you browsing to it. Check `mount` for anything interesting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is only one solution for this:
Map ( mount) a Samba server file path as a Local Disk Drive ( local path), 
then set `GOPATH` to this local path:

Mounting SMB share on local folder by using smbmount command (smbmount is deprecated):

```
smbmount //ipadd/sharename /mountpoint –o  username=userid,workgroup=workgroupname
```

Example :

```
smbmount //192.168.0.1/share1 /mnt –o username=steev,workgroup=test
```

Mounting SMB share by using mount command

```
mount –t smbfs ipadd:/sharename /mountpoint –o username=userid,workgroup=workgroupname
```

Or

```
mount –t smbfs //ipadd/sharename /mountpoint –o username=userid,workgroup=workgroupname
```

Example :

```
mount –t smbfs 192.168.0.1:/share1 /mnt –o username=surendra,workgroup=test
```

ref:
http://www.linuxnix.com/8-ways-to-mount-smbfs-samba-file-system-in-linux/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/232998/how-do-i-install-smbmount
http://www.howtogeek.com/116309/use-ubuntus-public-folder-to-easily-share-files-between-computers/
and for Windows:  https://serverfault.com/questions/6079/how-can-i-mount-an-ftp-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows

Comment: smbmount is deprecated.

Comment: @kristen : use mount  instead ( see ref )

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the Samba share to a folder on your machine:

```
$ mkdir /mnt/samba
$ smbmount smb://path/to/share /mnt/samba
```

Of course you may need to use switches on the `smbmount` command to provide username, password, workgroup, etc., depending on the configuration of the Samba share you're trying to access.  Once you've mounted the share you can then do

`$ export GOPATH=/mnt/samba`

And as far as Go is concerned the files in the Samba share will be located on your local machine.

Comment: I get "smbmount: command not found". If I try to install smbmount I get "Unable to locate package". I am using Linux Mint (Ubuntu).