# How do you share your GOPATH via Dropbox (or similar) across multiple platforms

Tags: go

I develop across 3 different platforms, Windows, OS X and Ubuntu Linux.
I use Dropbox to synchronize my code between all 3 platforms.
The problem I have is compiled binaries on OS X and Linux get the same name, so binaries in my `GOPATH` are always overwriting each other. I don't have this problem with Windows because binaries always compile with a `.exe` extension.

Has anyone else experienced this problem, and if so, how did you get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- set `GOBIN` to separate path (just e.g. for `OS X`) and use

`go install`

[Command go](https://golang.org/cmd/go/) :

> If the GOBIN environment variable is set, commands are installed to the
>   directory it names instead of DIR/bin. GOBIN must be an absolute path.

---

2- Also you may rename the output file:

```
go build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]
```

Like this:

```
go build -o newname
```

> The -o flag, only allowed when compiling a single package, forces
>   build to write the resulting executable or object to the named output
>   file.

---

Also see: [How do I use a Samba server location for GOPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679294/how-do-i-use-a-samba-server-location-for-gopath)

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple: only share the `$GOPATH/src` folder across your computers, there is really no need to share the complete `$GOPATH` as package objects (`$GOPATH/pkg`) and binaries (`$GOPATH/bin`) compiled to one platform have no real use on other platforms, and they are reproducible by a simple compilation.

This will also reduce the storage and bandwidth. If for some reason you would still need the compiled binaries for other platforms, the `go` tool has built-in support for cross compilation, e.g. `GOOS=windows go build` will simply produce you the Windows executable binary of the package whose folder you're in in any OS, placed in the current folder (you can also change the architecture with `GOARCH`).

Another option would be to put your code under a source control e.g. [git](https://git-scm.com/) ([github.com](https://github.com/)), which also preserves history. The `go` tool also has support to easily get the source code from a git repository, e.g. `go get -u github.com/youruser/yourpackage`.